# Order sql result by first occurence of string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Given the following sql statement:

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn like '%xyz%'
```

and the following result

```
aaxyz
bbbxyz
xyzcc
dxyzxd
eeeeexyz
```

How do I demand the sql statement to order the result in the rank of the **first occurence of the demanded string**, i.e. `xyzcc` first and `eeeeexyz` last?

Answer (score 1):

With the function [`position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) which returns the index of the first occurrence of a substring inside a string:

```
select * from mytable 
where mycolumn like '%xyz%'
order by position('xyz' in mycolumn)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/btvaYoxxpFmDZv7rbVXYNd/0).
Results:

```
| mycolumn |
| -------- |
| xyzcc    |
| dxyzxd   |
| aaxyz    |
| bbbxyz   |
| eeeeexyz |
```